# Is It Possible To "Transpose" The User's Location?

Tags: ios10, swift4

What I would like to do is specify a location (for instance, a street corner in Paris) and have an MKMapView treat that as the user's current position. As the user moves away from his/her true position the deltas are reflected as changes to that "transposed" location. In other words: can I fool an MKMapView into "believing" that I am standing wherever I choose in the world and have it track my movements as though I were actually there?

Edit:

Actually, the real question is: Can I fool Core Location and thereby fool an MKMapView? The application wherein I would be displaying the transposed MKMapView would be interacting with Core Location.